# Does PyCharm Debugger have a 'goto' option?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

For example, I have a breakpoint at `print('c')` and when the programs pauses I want to *jump* to `print('f')` (without executing `print('d')` and `print('e')`). Is that possible?

[image: debugging example]

PyCharm Version is: 2016.2.3, Community Edition.

Comment: I think PyCharm debugger has a "jump to cursor position" feature

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for. In some IDEs it is called "jump to cursor" or similar. But I still can't find it in PyCharm (nor in google or stackoverflow)

Comment: it is documented [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/stepping-through-the-program.html)

Comment: If you're referring to 'Force Run to Cursor' (which seems like the only reasonable thing you might refer to) then it still **runs** through your code; in other words, 'd' and 'e' will still be printed.